# RMI location of RMI-REGISTRY

Tags: java, rmi, distributed-computing

I would like to know if it is possibile in RMI to make start  RMIregistry in an host different from Server that offers the service.

Comment: @user2511414 Not much of a comment. Yes this is possible but it is both non-trivial and essentially pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible but inconvenient, because bind(), rebind(), and unbind() are only accepted from the localhost.

You would have to run a Registry in the host containing the server, another Registry in the second host, and another program in the second host to look up the first registry and bind the result into the second Registry, and to make sure the second binding appears and disappears when the first one does.

In other words it's pointless. The client can lookup the first Registry just as well as the auxiliary program can.

The other solution is to use an LDAP server instead of a Registry, and use Context.bind()/lookup().